# CSS 90% is not the same as computed 90% when nested

Tags: css, html

I came across this and couldn't find explanation anywhere.

For all the elements, padding and margin are set to 0.

```
CSS
---------
#mygrandparentdiv {
  height: 213px;
}
#myparentdiv {
  height: 90%;
}
#mydiv {
  height: 90%;
}
---------
HTML
---------
<div id='mygrandparentdiv'>
  <div id='myparentdiv'>
    <div id='mydiv'>Something here</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If I go to the developer tool to inspect the elements, the height of myparentdiv is 90% of mygrandparentdiv,which is 191.7px, but mydiv is 157.217px (82% of myparentdiv) and not 172.53px (90% of myparentdiv).

Why is this happening?

Comment: Calculates correctly for me in Chrome And FF.

Comment: Hmm...I just tried with a simple example, you are actually right. Not too sure which elements are messing with it. I'll try to get an incorrect example and edit the question.

Comment: do a jsfiddle like http://jsfiddle.net/9QD7f/ then you are sure everzone sees the same thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I realised what is causing the shrinking of height. It's all because of the scroll bar.

I have set up the jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/9QD7f/2/). So you can compare the top group and the bottom group, where the top group has a numbers of div with `#mydiv` whereas the second one has just one.

Thanks to [Hurda](https://stackoverflow.com/users/104856/hurda) for reminding me about jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

```
height:90%;
```

will be of the parent

http://jsfiddle.net/9QD7f/1/

I added a few more divs and gave them background colors. As you can see each one look like it is getting a different size thats because 90% of a smaller and smaller div is not going to give you a uniform "striping" at the bottom.

Inspecting it, the Math checks out. Each div is 90% of its immediate parent.